# restsharp AddParameter for POST not working on Mac (mono)

Tags: macos, mono, restsharp

Using RestSharp 104.4.0 on Xamarin 4.2.2.

I cannot figure out why RestSharp does not add the parameter to a POST request. I am hitting a REST API that takes both GET and POST.

Not working POST:

```
var request_post = new RestRequest ("folder/endpoint.php", Method.POST);
request_post.AddParameter("ref", "some/value");
response = client.Execute(request_post);
Console.WriteLine (response.Content);
```

Error is saying that ref parameter is required.

Working GET:

```
var request_get = new RestRequest ("folder/endpoint.php", Method.GET);
request_get.AddParameter("ref", "some/value");
response = client.Execute(request_get);
Console.WriteLine (response.Content);
```

Update:

It may be adding the parameter but I need to add the parameters as a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, [Matt](http://matthewschrager.com/2013/02/19/restsharp-post-body/).

```
// POST request.
// 
// This method does not work!
// var request_post = new RestRequest ("folder/endpoint.php", Method.POST);
// request_post.AddParameter("ref", "some/value");
// 
// This method does work.
var endpoint =  String.Format("folder/endpoint.php?{0}={1}", 
          "ref", "some/value");
var request_post = new RestRequest (endpoint, Method.POST);
response = client.Execute(request_post);
// Print out headers.
foreach (var header in response.Headers){
          Console.WriteLine(header);
}
// Print response.
Console.WriteLine(response.Content)
```